# is it necesary copy dependencies in Dockerfile when using containers for dev only?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, package.json

I want to create a dev enviroment for a node app with Docker. I have seen examples of Dockerfile with similar configurations as the following:

```
FROM node:14-alpine 
WORKDIR /express-api-server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I know that you can use volumes in docker-compose.yml to map host directories with directories of the containers using **Volumes**, thus you can make changes in your code and save data in a mongo database and preserve those changes locally when deleting or stopping container.
My question is: if I want to use the container for dev purposes only, there is any benefit on copying the package.json and package-lock.json, and installing dependencies?
I can use volumes to map the node_modules and the package files alonside with the code, so there's no need for me to take those action when building the image the first time.

Comment: What benefit are you getting from using Docker with this setup, over directly using Node on the host?

Answer (score 0):

correct. both work.
you just need to balance pros and cons.

the most obvious advantage is that having one dockerfile for dev and prod is easier and garanty that the environment is the same.

i personally have a single dockerfile for dev / test / prod for max coherence. and i mount volume with code and dependencies for dev.

when i do "npm install" i do it on the host. it instantly restarts the project without needing to rebuild. then when i want to publish to prod i do a docker build. it rebuils everything. ignoring mounts.

if you do like me, check that host nodejs version and docker's nodejs version is the same.

Comment: I'm happy to know that I wasn't mistaken. thanks!
I have seen that you can use a single Dockerfile and changing the way you build the image with env variables, this way you can install run the app with nodemoon in dev and not use it in prod. You do something like that, don't you?

thanks for the last recommendation, I'd rather use the docker image node version instead of host version to prevent future errors!!